# Could not able run iOSApp in Kotlin multiplatform in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, multiplatform

An error occurs when run iOSApp in KMM(Android studio), Could not able to configure schema. please see the attachment.

[image: Error attachment]

Comment: Hello, @Gan! Please check this particular .xcodeproj file presence. If it exists, try opening it with the Xcode and build from there, just to check if it was not broken during the download or whatever.

Answer (score 14):

Go to `XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools` => Select desired version of Xcode. This worked for me.

Comment: This helps to fix "Error: Could not detect version of installed Xcode"! You may need to restart android studio after doing this.

Comment: Thanks @Nilay-Dagdemir. Note: Even if it is already selected, you just need to reselect the Xcode again and then restart the Android Studio.

Answer (score 11):

Run in console
`xcode-select --print-path`

I got this result
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

And it should be something like
`/Applications/Xcode${xcode-number}/Xcode.app`

So run in console
`cd /Applications`

Then run in console
`ls -la`

If you see `Xcode.app`

- Then you run example 1 in console

Else if you see something like
`Xcode 8.0.3`

- Then you run example 2 in console

Now you should run this in console
`sudo xcode-select -switch ${path-to-xcode.app}/Xcode.app`

example 1
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

example 2
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode 8.0.3/Xcode.app`

Update:

I also found this
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41691

Comment: This also helps to fix "Error: Could not detect version of installed Xcode"!