# Android Studio KMM Application project - Build for ios platform failing

Tags: ios, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I am a first time on KMM and have just created a new KMM application project on Macbook M1 Pro. No code changes, this is just the hello world app. I have been able to successfully build the project for Android platform, and it runs fine on the Android emulator. However, when I try to build it for the iOS platform, it is failing with the below error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':shared'.
> The project must have a target for at least one of the following platforms: ios_simulator_arm64.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 553ms
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\ shared /Users/manajit/Projects/Learning/App/KMMExperiment/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-4552119A071AC6BAB7327E6434237EC3.sh (in target 'shared' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the base application created by the KMM plugin has commented out support for the ARM simulator because there are some libraries that do not yet support it. This is most likely due to Ktor, which only recently added its support.

Go to `shared/build.gradle.kts` and uncomment all lines containing `iosSimulatorArm64`.

Comment: There is no line with iosSimulatorArm64 in the shared/build.gradle.kts. The file content is:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}

Comment: @ManajitRath no, this looks like a content of `projectDir/build.gradle.kts`, make sure you're looking at shared module one

Comment: I am so sorry, yes, I checked the shared/build,gradle.kts and found iosSimulatorArm64 and uncommented the same throughout. Now the build fails with the error:e: /Users/manajit/Projects/Learning/App/KMMFirst/shared/build.gradle.kts:13:25: Unresolved reference: sure
e: /Users/manajit/Projects/Learning/App/KMMFirst/shared/build.gradle.kts:13:30: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val <T : Configuration> NamedDomainObjectProvider<TypeVariable(T)>.all: Set<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Comment: @ManajitRath line 13 contains note about why it was commented, you can delete string "sure all ios dependencies support this target"

Comment: Yayyy... This worked fine. The emulator did start up for ios.. However, once the emulator starts up it throws an error.. "Android Studio quit unexpectedly." and it asks me to restart AndroidStudio..

Comment: @ManajitRath I haven't faced such problem, try running it from Xcode.

Comment: It throws an error while building on xcode. "ld: framework not found Pods_iosApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @ManajitRath try runing `pod install` from `project/iosApp`

Comment: I ran pod install. It ran successfully, but the build still fails on xCode and same behaviour on AS.

Comment: @ManajitRath it's hard to say with these details. Upload the project on GitHub, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Xcode and I fixed it by putting `arm64` into Excluded Architectures.

Target > Build Settings > Excluded Architectures > Add `Any iOS Simulator SDK` for each scheme with the value of `arm64`, like on the image:

[image: 123]

Then delete Derived Data through Xcode or by hitting command:
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

If this does not work, search for `VALID_ARCHS` in Build Settings. If you have that and the value is `arm64`, make sure to remove it.

Comment: Still didn't help