# Kotlin Multiplatform not grabbing XCode Scheme

Tags: xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to use Kotlin Multiplatform but the "XCode Project Scheme" isn't showing anything when I try to make a new configuration for iOS.

Im currently using:
iOS Version 10.15.7
Android Studio Version:4.1.2

I've already made the changes suggested this link [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41691). (Open XCode->Preferences->Locations-> Select CLI)
And also follow the instructions suggested by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030601/could-not-able-run-iosapp-in-kotlin-multiplatform-in-android-studio)
If a run the following line in terminal

```
 xcode-select --print-path
```

It shows:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Try this :- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44805

Comment: Hi, @LizardStd! Maybe the problem is caused by the Android Studio version? See [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-44760#focus=Comments-27-4692782.0-0) and below. AS 4.1 should work fine only with KMM 0.2.0 and before, with Kotlin plugin version 1.4.20(and it would work better if the project uses this version too). Anyway, adding plugin versions info to the question should help to localize the cause.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Yes, you are right about this. It was the AS Version, I'm now using the newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/kmm-plugin-releases.html#release-details) page from KMM Plugin documentation.
Android Studio 4.1.* should work fine for KMM Plugin 2.0.0 AND Kotlin plugin 1.4.2*. If either of those plugins will be updated, one cannot guarantee stable and correct work.
So, when you want to use Kotlin 1.4.3* or later, you got to

1. Install AS 4.2 Beta or Canary Android Studio([Android Studio Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)).
2. Update Kotlin plugin to 1.4.30 or later(better use the latest version).
3. Update KMM Plugin to 2.0.1 or later(2.0.2 for Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary 8, [see issue here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45162?_ga=2.161598015.2065231360.1615793250-801466193.1615388297)).

After those steps, KMM Plugin should be working fine. If you face any issues with that, consider reporting them to [kotl.in/issue](http://kotl.in/issue).